# How to get the version of a package loaded via require in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a few installed versions of a package.

I load the package:

```
const File = require('vinyl');
```

But it seems the loaded version is not the latest. How can I view the version of the loaded package?

Comment: Go to `node_modules/vinyl/package.json` and it should state the package version there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require('vinyl/package.json').version
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But would be better if package itself had information about version and etc.

Comment: @wishmaster35 fs is core package. They don't have ```package.json``` in a directory. Use ```process.version``` to see which ```node``` version you are running.